# Convert YAML files to CSV (Excel) /dev/sda problem

Tags: python, excel, csv, yaml, typeerror

I have 100 similar yml files and need to parse all of this files into one csv file. I don't have much practice in python :(
This yaml files look like this:

```
/dev/sda:
    devname: /dev/sda
    id_model: INTEL_SSDSC2KB240G7
    id_serial_short: PHYS746602EV240AGN
/dev/sdaa:
    devname: /dev/sdaa
    id_model: INTEL_SSDSC2KG019T8
    id_serial_short: PHYG013000UX1P9DGN
/dev/sdb:
    devname: /dev/sdb
    id_model: INTEL_SSDSC2KB240G7
    id_serial_short: PHYS745207RL240AGN
/dev/sdc:
    devname: /dev/sdc
    id_model: INTEL_SSDSC2KG019T8
    id_serial_short: PHYG9271045G1P9DGN
/dev/sdd:
    devname: /dev/sdd
    id_model: INTEL_SSDSC2KG019T8
    id_serial_short: PHYG013000EP1P9DGN
```

It's the small part of one file.
I tried to use and modify this code, but I don't get how to parse this ("/dev/sda"), it's just don't want to work:

```
import yaml
import csv
import glob

yaml_file_names = glob.glob('/home/ranburu/Downloads/disks_info/*.yml')

rows_to_write = []

for i, each_yaml_file in enumerate(yaml_file_names):
    print("Processing file {} of {} file name: {}".format(
        i + 1, len(yaml_file_names), each_yaml_file))

    with open(each_yaml_file) as file:
        data = yaml.safe_load(file)
        for instance in data['/dev/sd*']:
            # values = dict()
            # for tag in instance["tags"]:
            #     tag_for_check = tag.split(":")
            #
            #     if tag_for_check[0] == "ip":
            #         values["ip"] = tag_for_check[1]
            #         continue
            #
            #     elif tag_for_check[0] == "name":
            #         values["name"] = tag_for_check[1]

            rows_to_write.append([each_yaml_file, instance["id_model"], instance["id_serial_short"]])

with open('output_csv_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as out:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(out)
    csv_writer.writerow(["host", "model", "serial"])
    csv_writer.writerows(rows_to_write)
    print("Output file output_csv_file.csv created")
```

At the end I have this error:

```
line 15, in <module>
    for instance in data['/dev/sd*']:
KeyError: '/dev/sd*'
```

I fugure out how this code works, but this /dev/sda,sdb,sdc in start of each block just baffle me.
I will be very grateful if you can help me with this problem and write a code that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yaml.safe_load` will process the yaml into a dictionary. This means you can then iterate over it using the standard dictionary methods (i.e. no need to try to parse it as strings with `split` etc).

Assuming you want each column to be the values of the 3 entries in each nested dict, we can take advantage of the items being added to the dict in order and just use `values()` to extract them. The following demonstrates the process with a single bit of yaml data - but it should be easy to nest this inside the code iterating over all the files:

```
import csv
import yaml

yml = """
/dev/sda:
    devname: /dev/sda
    id_model: INTEL_SSDSC2KB240G7
    id_serial_short: PHYS746602EV240AGN
/dev/sdaa:
    devname: /dev/sdaa
    id_model: INTEL_SSDSC2KG019T8
    id_serial_short: PHYG013000UX1P9DGN
"""

data = yaml.safe_load(yml)

with open('output_csv_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as out:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(out)
    csv_writer.writerow(["host", "model", "serial"])
    for disk in data.values():
        csv_writer.writerows([disk.values()])

# output_csv_file.csv
host,model,serial
/dev/sda,INTEL_SSDSC2KB240G7,PHYS746602EV240AGN
/dev/sdaa,INTEL_SSDSC2KG019T8,PHYG013000UX1P9DGN
```

Comment: Thank you for your ansver, yes, this kinda work, but I have another error: 

csv_writer.writerows([disk.values()])
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'values'

I think this error appears because there are two lines whith true value at the end of the each file:

changed: false
failed: false


And I want to put name of the each file in the first column. How can I do this?